# CSS display: none; not working for a condition given in media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, screen, display

I'm trying to target devices of widths `<= 375px` and `=> 376px` (mobile and desktop respectively). I've created link tags in my HTML, with different media queries linking to respective CSS files. Here's my code:

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="mobile.css"
            media=" screen and (max-width: 375px)" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="desktop.css"
            media=" screen and (min-width: 376px)" />
</head>
<body>
        <div class="img-section">
            <img src="images/image-product-desktop.jpg" id="desktop" alt="" />
            <img src="images/image-product-mobile.jpg" id="mobile" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="parent">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati,
            quo cupiditate similique consequuntur perferendis at asperiores
            officiis praesentium repellat aspernatur!
        </div>
</body>
```

Code for desktop.css:

```css
html {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-section {
    text-align: center;
}
img#mobile {
    display: none;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Code for mobile.css:

```css
html {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

body {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-section {
    text-align: center;
}
img#desktop {
    display: none;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```

So, I use the `display: none;` to determine which image is displayed based on the device.

I notice when the `width` is exactly `375px` the mobile.css is used by the browser, but the two images `img#desktop` and `img#mobile` are displayed, instead of only just `img#mobile`.

I tried to fix it by adding this to the mobile.css:

```css
@media screen and (width: 375px) {
    img#desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

but it didn't work.

I really want to know if this is caused by any mistake I made or something I need to add, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommend that you follow the principle of mobile-first design. Use a single style sheet, which, as a starting point, contains all the styles you want for mobile. Then, for any style rule which needs adjusting for desktop, add a `@media (min-width: xxx)` rule **after** it to **override** the mobile style with desktop style.

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100svh;
}

@media (min-width: 376px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

.img-section {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}

img#desktop {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 376px) {
  img#desktop {
    display: initial;
  }
  img#mobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="img-section">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/8/300" id="desktop" alt="" />
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/160/300" id="mobile" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="parent">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati,
  quo cupiditate similique consequuntur perferendis at asperiores
  officiis praesentium repellat aspernatur!
</div>
```

Comment: I really do appreciate your answer and recommendation Sir. I've tested it and it works. But isn't there a fix for the issue in using my approach of using different stylesheet files Sir?

Comment: Your problem arises because browsers may calculate the screen width in fractional pixels. You're seeing two images because the width is being calculated as 375.5 (say), which means that neither stylesheet is being applied. You can "fix" it by using 375 as both the maximum in one case and the minimum in the other case -- this would result in both stylesheets being applied if the width is exactly 375, but the later one would simply override the earlier one. Better to have two stylesheets applied than none. But the best solution of all is to have only one stylesheet all the time.

Comment: Okay. I understand the point. I've tested the "fix" and seen that at exactly 375px, the desktop.css is applied. But isn't there a way to revert "the later" to be the mobile.css?

Comment: Change the order they are declared in your code. Declare desktop.css first, then mobile.css second.

Comment: I've changed the order of the link tags in the HTML code. But desktop.css still wins.